# In R determine bi frequency of categorical data from two data frames with time dependency

Tags: r, probability

I have two data frames, one contains fault information during equipment operation, and the second contains maintenance actions.  Is there a way to determine the probability of a maintenance action given a previous fault.

```
# Sample problem
# Determine frequency table from two data sources to determine
# if events are sequential

# Generate N random dates in a range
randDates <- function(N, st="2014/01/01", et="2014/06/30") {
     st <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(st))
     et <- as.POSIXct(as.Date(et))
     dt <- as.numeric(difftime(et,st,unit="sec"))
     ev <- sort(runif(N, 0, dt))
     rt <- st + ev
}

# generate two data sets
# smOper contains operational data that has events
#   the event time, event name, and serial number
# smMain contains maintenance data that has actions
#   the maintenance action, the maintence time, and the serial number 

set.seed(1234)
nSerial = 10
nEventTypes = 10
nOpersPerSerial = 100
nOps = nOpersPerSerial*nSerial
oper_df <- data.frame(time = randDates(nOps),
             fault = paste("Event_",sample(1:nEventTypes,nOps,replace=T),sep=""),
             serialNo = sample(1:nSerial,nOps,replace=T))

nMaintenancePerSerial = 30
nMaintenanceActions = 20       
nMaint = nMaintenancePerSerial * nSerial
maint_df <- data.frame(time = randDates(nOps),
             action = paste("Action_",sample(1:nMaintenanceActions,nOps,replace=T),sep=""),
             serialNo = sample(1:nSerial,nOps,replace=T))

# Show the frequency of events and actions by serial number

oper_table <- with(oper_df,table(fault,serialNo))
maint_table <- with(maint_df,table(action,serialNo))

# How to determine the frequency of maintenance actions with previous operational faults 
# on the same serial no? 

temp1_df <- data.frame(serialNo = oper_df$serialNo, time = oper_df$time,
             fault = oper_df$fault,
             action = NA,
             source="OPS")
temp2_df <- data.frame(serialNo = maint_df$serialNo, time = maint_df$time,
             action = maint_df$action,
             fault=NA,
             source="MAINT")
opsMaint_df <- rbind(temp1_df, temp2_df)
opsMaint_df <- opsMaint_df[with(opsMaint_df,order(serialNo,time)),]
head(opsMaint_df)

temp1_df <- data.frame(serialNo = oper_df$serialNo, time = oper_df$time,
             info = oper_df$fault,
             source="OPS")
temp2_df <- data.frame(serialNo = maint_df$serialNo, time = maint_df$time,
             info = maint_df$action,
             source="MAINT")
opsMaint_df2 <- rbind(temp1_df, temp2_df)
opsMaint_df2 <- opsMaint_df2[with(opsMaint_df2,order(serialNo,time)),]
head(opsMaint2_df)

with(opsMaint_df,table(action,fault))
```

Now, I would like a table with operational events in the column headers, and maintenance
actions in the row headers, and the row/column intersection is the number of time that the event occurred before the action for a serial number.

Looking at the first 10 items

```
     serialNo                time      info source
1001        1 2013-12-31 22:53:07  Action_4  Maint
5           1 2014-01-01 04:16:25   Event_8    Ops
8           1 2014-01-01 09:10:46   Event_2    Ops
1005        1 2014-01-01 23:06:27 Action_10  Maint
1009        1 2014-01-02 08:48:12  Action_1  Maint
11          1 2014-01-02 12:01:18   Event_5    Ops
1011        1 2014-01-02 15:10:40  Action_3  Maint
1031        1 2014-01-05 11:06:17 Action_17  Maint
24          1 2014-01-05 11:43:07  Event_10    Ops
1041        1 2014-01-06 15:57:40 Action_17  Maint
```

Counting the events that occur before an action

```
          event
action    Event_2 Event_5 Event_8 Event_10
Action_1        1       0       1        0
Action_3        1       1       1        0
Action_4        0       0       0        0
Action_10       1       0       1        0
Action_17       2       2       2        1
```

Here's my attempt to solve using loops.  This seems to produce the correct results, but probably takes too long.

```
# For each group of rows that corresponds to a serial number
#   For each row 
#     if the source is Maint then count the number of prior Faults
#     total the number of faults in a (Action, Fault) array

freqCount <- function(df) {
  # Frequency counting using loops
  uSerial <- sort(unique(df$serialNo))
  uFault <- sort(unique(df$info[df$source=="OPS"]))
  uAction <- sort((unique(df$info[df$source=="MAINT"])))
  freq <- data.frame(matrix(0, nrow = length(uAction), ncol = length(uFault)), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  names(freq)<-uFault
  row.names(freq)<-uAction

  for (iSerial in seq(uSerial)) {
    serialRows = which(df$serialNo == uSerial[iSerial])
    for (jRow in seq(serialRows)) {
      if (df$source[serialRows[jRow]] == "MAINT") {
        actn = as.character(df$info[serialRows[jRow]])
        for (kRow in seq(1,(jRow-1))) {
          if (kRow >= 1) {
            kInfo = as.character(df$info[serialRows[kRow]])
            if (df$source[serialRows[kRow]] == "OPS") { 
              freq[actn, kInfo ] <- freq[actn, kInfo ] + 1
            } else if (actn == kInfo) {
              break
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  freq<-rbind(freq,colSums(freq))
  freq<-cbind(freq,rowSums(freq))
  names(freq)[ncol(freq)]<-"rowSums"
  row.names(freq)[nrow(freq)]<-"colSums"
  freq
}

# Reduce the amount of data to match example
#
freqCount(opsMaint_df2[1:10,])
# Analyze all the data
#
freqCount(opsMaint_df2)
```

Here's an attempt using zoo merge / aggregate.  But the merge creates an object with NA in the first 10 rows?

```
# zoo merge / aggregate frequency counting
require(zoo)
maint_z <- zoo(maint_df[,c("serialNo","action")],order.by=maint_df$time)
oper_z <- zoo(oper_df[,c("serialNo","fault")],order.by=oper_df$time)
zdf <- merge(oper_z, maint_z)
head(zdf)
```

How to aggregate zdf by action for prior fault grouped by serial no?

Comment: Seems feasible with some aggregation and merging. Provide some sample data so that the coding can begin.

Comment: @BondedDust added the sample data tables, combined the two data tables, and sorted by serial number and date.  Now the question is how to determine the frequency table between alerts and actions to count alerts that occur before actions, for the same serial number.

Comment: Take a look to [The Quick-R tutorial: Reshaping data](http://statmethods.net/management/reshape.html)

Comment: The section of code that creates your test case threw a warning from this line: `opsMaint_df <- opsMaint_df[with(opsMaint_df,order(serialNo,time,-source)),]`. Ha you used `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` the 'OPS'-column would have been "character". Do you have control of how this data is input to R?  If so would I think it be more sensible to use stringsAsFactors=FALSE so that sorting and other ordinary character operations would succeed.

Comment: If you accept my suggestion, it will require using `rev()` instead of "-" when reversing the sort order character columns with `order`.

Comment: In the real situation the numbers of case of 'maintenance' and 'faults' cannot be the same, right? So I'm suggesting that  a merge operation based on time would be more successful and the proper platform to accomplish this is the zoo-package.

Comment: There is a wide difference in the count of alerts and actions, and they each have their own times.  So, I don't see how a merge is better than a rbind. @BondedDust

Comment: Regarding -source and rev(), I later realized the same serial number can not have alerts and actions at the same time.  The alerts occur during operation, and the actions occur during maintenance while the unit is not operated.  Forgot to go back and update the example code here. @BondedDust

Comment: I don't see how reshaping helps. @Barranka

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61185/discussion-between-user3969377-and-bondeddust).

Comment: Just skimming the question, it seems like you can get this done with `table`/`xtabs` and `prop.table`, along with clever subsetting.

Comment: Any suggestions are appreciated.  The maint actions have to be selected for subset that is more associated with usage degreneration / wear.  The usage faults may have to be subset, at least to only count one pairing with an action.

Comment: Does anyone know of reports on frequency / statistics between faults and maintenance, for condition based maintenance?